# iteratively adding values to a column of a dataframe in R

Tags: r, dataframe, iteration

I have a for-loop that reads a file into a dataframe. I would like to add a column (file_name) so that the name of each file appears next to the observations from that file.

I have the following code:

```
dummy_variable <- 0
for (i in files){ 
  df <- read.delim(paste('FOLDER/', i, sep=''), sep='\t', header=F)
 df$file_name[(dummy_variable+1):(nrow(df))] <- i
  dummy_variable <-nrow(df)
...
}
```

The code does not work. How can I correct it?

Comment: Changing the above to:  `
for (i in files){ 
  df <- read.delim(paste('FOLDER/', i, sep=''), sep='\t', header=F)
 df$file_name<- i
 
...
} ` does not work either.

Comment: Are you reading in multiple files that you want to row bind into a single data.frame, with a column indicating which file that observation came from?

Comment: I am reading in multiple files, modifying them, and then writing them as csv files.

Comment: What is the significance of `dummy_variable <-nrow(df)` changing iteratively?

Comment: @diomesdata That's my mistake. Thank you for spotting it. Would the following code be better? `for (i in files){ 
  df <- read.delim(paste('FOLDER/', i, sep=''), sep='\t', header=F)
 df$file_name[1:(nrow(df))] <- i

...
}

Comment: Why doesn't simply `df$file_name <- i` work, assuming `files` is a character vector.

Comment: Great! I’m going to vote to close this as a duplicate so there aren’t a huge number of posts on the same topic.